# Python: Adding Arguments to Arguments using Argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to add an argument to another one using argparse? If so, how would one implement this.

The following example shows what I'm actually looking for:

```
--plt <some_file> -opt <some_number>
```

Here, `--plt` is an argument with several options. `-opt` is hence depending on `--plt`.

So if a user provides `--plt` as argument, he/she has to provide `-opt`, too. `-opt` alone is also not a valid argument to the script.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--test', '-test', help='performs classification test')
parser.add_argument('--plt','-plt', help='plots loss function')
parser.add_argument('--version', '-version>', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.1')
```

Comment: Parse using argparse. Then, you would check -opt **if-and-only-if** --plt argument is detected ? In other words, some user could specify -opt, but withuot --plt, it would not be taken into account by your program.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Well, if you agree with my "answer", show your code so we can understand your problem. :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But, if you want to do it all with argparse, then I'm afraid it's not. You can always simply use conditional statements to check what arguments the user is using.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was doing it this way but it felt like working agains argparse but I didn't found any reference for such task online.

Comment: `argparse` does not have an `inclusive-and` mechanism comparable to the `mutually-exclusive` one.  In some case `subparsers` do the job nicely.  But there's nothing wrong with doing your own testing.  `argparse` is a parser, not a complete controller.